# Is there a .NET equivalent to C's atoi function?

Tags: .net, atoi

If I have a string like:

```
"26 things"
```

I want to convert it to 26.  I just want the integer at the beginning of the string.

If I was using C, I'd just use the atoi function.  But I can't seem to find anything equivalent in .NET.

What's the easiest way to grab the integer from the beginning of a string?

**Edit:** I'm sorry I was ambiguous.  The answers that look for a space character in the string will work in many circumstances (perhaps even mine).  I was hoping for an atoi-equivalent in .NET.  The answer should also work with a string like "26things".  Thanks.

Comment: I am curious to see how you do that with ATOI() with the space and without the space. You can't just call ATOI(yourString)... because the function first discards as many whitespace characters as necessary until the *first* non-whitespace character is found...

Comment: I don't understand your question.  atoi would return 26 with either string.

Comment: 26things without a space doesn't have a space so ATOI would try to parser not only 26 but the whole string isn't?

Comment: atoi will stop at the first non-digit.  So 26things would parse to 26.  atoi only considers whitespace in that it skips over the initial whitespace.  Once it finds the number, it will stop at any non-digit character.  26.9 would parse to 26.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work (edited to ignore white-space at the begining of the string)

```
int i = int.Parse(Regex.Match("26 things", @"^\s*(\d+)").Groups[1].Value);
```

If you are worried about checking if there is a value you could do the following to give you a -1 value if there is no integer at the begining of the string.

```
Match oMatch = Regex.Match("26 things", @"^\s*(\d+)");
int i = oMatch.Success ? int.Parse(oMatch.Groups[1].Value) : -1;
```

Comment: Oh please, no regex for such a trivial task.

Comment: @Noldorin - Why not, it's a perfectly valid use of regex. I'm not sure why this needs a down-vote just because you would do it differently?

Comment: @Stevo: It's simply overkill when you can use string splitting/simple text manipulation. (And a lot more efficient, though this may or may not matter.) Down vote removed however, since you are right - it is still a valid solution.

Comment: @Noldorin: Why not? For simple tasks like these, the regex is actually easily readable. To be honest, I find it clearer than your solution.

Comment: @Noldorin - Simple text manipulation will not work as efficiently nor as simply as a regular expression in this case. I agree that regular expressions can be abused, but this is a great case for using one.

Comment: Wondering why I've still got a down-vote for an answer that answers the question and is easily readable?

Comment: I was torn.  I posted this question to see how I could do it without a regex.  But your answer is concise and readable.  I upvoted Noldorin's "please no regex" comment, but this is still the best answer.  It does seem ironic that the trivial and fast atoi function is best emulated with the complex regex engine.

Comment: To match atoi, the regex should be ^\s*\d+

Comment: If "26 things" or "26things" is a variable passed into this, then you can potentially get some exceptiosn. If the input string is null you'll get a NullReferenceException. If there are no digits or any non-digit character(s) (like whitespace or '-') at the start of the string you'll get a FormatException because the regex returns an empty string. You can even an OverflowException if the number extracted is greater than int.MaxValue or less than int.MinValue.

Comment: @Brian Reiter - The code is obviously not error trapped, it is just a quick example.

Comment: By default, int.Parse will ignore whitespace, so you don't need to use the regex group.

Comment: @Stevo300. My point was really that atoi() wouldn't throw an excpetion it would just return 0 if there was no number in the string. I think it would also just wrap the integer around if it overflowed but not sure on that one.

Comment: @Brian Reiter - If a 0 value is required as default then my second code example could have the -1 changed to 0.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein - I realise the group could be discarded, but using it makes what the code is doing much clearer (readability is especially important where using regex) and removes the possiblity of hard to find bugs if the default parse behaviour changes.

Comment: Considering this is the "best answer", and how precise stackoverflow answers are expected to be, I am surprised that nobody has commented that `atoi()` accepts negative integer strings (and I need that). So a better RegEx would be `@"^\s*-?(\d+)"`.  Or as per e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi ("(optional) plus or minus sign") `@"^\s*[+-]?(\d+)"`

Answer (score 14):

This looks sooo beautiful:

```
string str = "26 things";
int x = int.Parse(str.TakeWhile(ch => char.IsDigit(ch)).Aggregate("", (s, ch) => s + ch));
```

And, the boring solution for anyone who really wants atoi:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int atoi(string str);
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Regex works too but I was going with this for practice. Also meets the OPs clarified requirements.

Comment: I love this answer.  It matches the spirit of atoi.  I just think it's a little hard to read, at least for me, so I accepted the regex.

Comment: +1. I prefer the LINQ over Regex. You can also improve on this by adding a SkipWhile to ignore any text before the number (in case of "There are 26 things") and it would be even more robust.

Comment: Also, I would split the steps so you have see the string to be parsed instead of cramming it all in one line.

Comment: To completely match the atoi functionality, you should first trim the string.

Comment: int.Parse(new string(str.TakeWhile(ch => char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray())); works too and is shorter. I would suspect it's also faster, but I couldn't say without benchmarking

Comment: Yes, that should be faster. Aggregate will create count-of-chars temporary string objects. Anyone looking for speed can take approach #2 :-)

Comment: So the best answer using LINQ is: **int.Parse(new string(str.Trim().TakeWhile(ch => char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray()));**

Comment: @C.B. you can even shorten that to `int.Parse(new string(str.Trim().TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray()))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Int32.Parse(stringVal.Substring(0, stringVal.indexOf(" "))`

Comment: That would work for me.  I was wondering if there was a more atoi-like answer that didn't require the number to be followed by a space.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be

```
string sample = "26 things";
int x = int.Parse(sample.Substring(0, sample.IndexOf(" ")));
```

Comment: doesn't work with "26things" which would be no problem for atoi

Comment: Lame excuse but let me try: That was not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The direct equivalent is int.Parse(string) but I'm not entirely sure if that will take just the starting number.

Comment: I think you might have to write a specific function yourself to grab the number part, perhaps using the .NET String.Substring() function..?

Comment: It throws an exception on non-numeric data.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I suspected.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein: use int.TryParse() instead

Comment: @Jasper Bekkers: TryParse would give me 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Val in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion namespace.  In your scenario it should print "26". I don't know if it's 100% compatible in toher scenarios though. Here's a link to the specification.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: It returns 26123 for the string "26   123" which is not what atoi would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only whole number

```
public String GetNumber (String input)
{
    String result = "";
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsNumber(input[i]))
        {
            result += input[i];
        }
        else break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int i = int.Parse("26 things".Split(new Char[] {' '})[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

I can think just in something like this:

```
    public static string Filter(string input, string validChars) {
        int i;
        string result = "";
        for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
            if (validChars.IndexOf(input.Substring(i, 1)) >= 0) {
                result += input.Substring(i, 1);
            } else break;
        }
        return result ;
    }
```

And call it :

```
Filter("26 things", "0123456789");
```

Comment: I would argue if you're going to take that path then you should just use regular expressions.

Comment: Well, you maybe right... but anyway my solution is better than the ones using .IndexOf(" ")

Answer (score -2):

You've got to split the string and then parse it:

```
var str = "26 things";
var count = int.Parse(str.Split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: what for a string like 26things?

Comment: Such a format was not specified in the question. If it is possible, the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: This is not in the requirement first of all.. with ATOI the guy whould have to specify the pointer length too. This is a valid option.

Comment: @Noldorin - Not true, he asked 'What's the easiest way to grab the integer from the beginning of a string?', and 26things fits this criteria. Thre is no mention of a format other than integer at begining of string!

Comment: Well, I did say equivalent to atoi in the title.  I'll clarify.